# RxJava TestSubscriber / TestSingleSubscriber

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, rx-java

I have troubles with writing a test for `Single` operator. For some reason `Subscriber` is marked as `unsubscribed` just after creation.

Snippet of code:

```
public abstract class OneShotUseCase<T> {

    @NonNull
    private CompositeSubscription subscription = new CompositeSubscription();

    public void cancel() {
        subscription.clear();
    }

    public void execute(@NonNull SingleSubscriber<T> subscriber) {
        subscription.add(
                build().subscribe(subscriber)
        );
    }

    @NonNull
    protected abstract Single<T> build();
}
```

Test for that:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class OneShotUseCaseTest {

    private OneShotUseCase<String> sut;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        sut = new TestUseCase();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBuildUseCase() {
        final TestSingleSubscriber<String> stringTestSingleSubscriber = new TestSingleSubscriber<>();

        sut.execute(stringTestSingleSubscriber);

        stringTestSingleSubscriber.assertValue("Test value");
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCancelUseCase() {
        final TestSingleSubscriber<String> stringTestSingleSubscriber = new TestSingleSubscriber<>();

        sut.execute(stringTestSingleSubscriber);
        sut.cancel();

        stringTestSingleSubscriber.assertUnsubscribed();
    }


    private static class TestUseCase extends OneShotUseCase<String> {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        protected Single<String> build() {
            return Single.just("Test value");
        }
    }
}
```

As `TestSingleSubscriber` I am using following code: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/3834

My test fails at line `stringTestSingleSubscriber.assertUnsubscribed();`

I tried to dig little bit, but I found nothing before for such issue.

Is it something wrong with my understanding of **RxJava Single**?

Worth to mention that very similar code with `Observable<T>` instead of `Single` works in test perfectly.

I hope to find some ideas here how to make it working.

Comment: It might be of help to note the documentation, which says 
```A Single will call only one of these methods, and will only call it once. Upon calling either method, the Single terminates and the subscription to it ends
```

So, effectively, the `Single` emits its value and terminates immediately you subscribe to it.

Comment: Good point, but I guess even then `assertUnsubscribed` should not fail, right?

Comment: When you run the tests, `shouldBuildUsecase` would run and pass successfully. At which point `sut` would have been terminated. Try and create a new `sut` for each test case, see if that works for you

Comment: That's what is used for @Before annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to great RxJava community, I can post working solution:

```
 public void execute(@NonNull SingleSubscriber<T> subscriber) {
        build().subscribe(subscriber);
        subscription.add(subscriber);
    }
```

Problem lies in implementation details how `subscribe` method works for `Single` and `Observable`.

Issue was solved on Github, so I am posting the link: 
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4193